# Activate jQuery uniform for elements not added yet?

Tags: jquery, uniform

I am using jQuery `uniform()`:

```
$(el).uniform();
```

It works fine, but it does not apply to elements I add later through AJAX. How can I use this for future elements?

Comment: what do you mean by future objects?

Comment: Future objects mean... ajax creating more objects like checkboxes but they are not uniformed.

Comment: You need to initialize again after adding dynamic element using `$(el).uniform();`

Comment: I know this solution but I don't want to re-initialize... Is it possible without re-initialization.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to apply it to all future elements added. jQuery does not work that way. You will have to reapply the `uniform()` every time you load new content. However, for performance reasons you might not want to apply it to the same element twice. That can be avoided by adding a class to those elements who have had it applied. Every time you apply it, including the first time, use this:

```
$(el).filter(":not(.has-uniform)").addClass("has-uniform").uniform();
```

This only select those elements that does not have the class `has-uniform`, then adds that class and finally applies uniform.

For performance reasons, again, you might want to consider also limiting the function to the element where new things have been added. Let's say you have just added new content to a DOM element object `x`. Then you can use this to only search that element:

```
$(el, x).filter(":not(.has-uniform)").addClass("has-uniform").uniform();
```

Also, if you know that `x` was empty before you added new things to it you can skip the `filter` part.

I should add that I do not know if the performance is of any importance here. You could also just try to reapply it without any extra fuss.

Comment: Thank you Anders for your explanation... But unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. I know all about this that I can re-initialize objects and performance issue is not concern...anyway thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This is the only solution to your problem. There is *no* way of telling jQuery to automatically reapply a function when new elements are added. Please explain why you can't just reapply the function.

Comment: OKay, thank you very much... Reason is that too many elements are adding randomly using ajax.. I don't want to re-initialize.. I was looking for solution that every object should be uniformed automatically. I was already using re-initialization..

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing, in the end I did it like this for dynamically added items:

```
$('select').each(function() {
    $(this).not('[id^="uniform-"] *').uniform();
});
```

**The logic is:** If the item is not already a child of an element which has an id that starts with "uniform-" then add uniform (which sets a parent with an id that starts with id="uniform-..."